# SSMS: query export to Excel

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms, export-to-excel

I am trying to export 260+ column query to Excel from SSMS 2005.

When I finish up the wizard, I get the "Too many fields defined" error.

Is there any way of getting around this?

I suppose I can run that query via New Query and copy and paste to Excel but it doesn't copy over the column names.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem of your version of Excel other than SQL Server. If you have Excel 2003 (or an older version), then you only have 256 columns, so you won't be able to "get around this". For Excel 2007+, you shouldn't have a problem at all. By the way, you can still select all records after you run your query, right-click in the results, and select "copy with headers" to get the column names.

Comment: I have Office 2010 (Excel 2010) but I guess when you go through the wizard, it only gives you the options for 97-2003 Excel. Any way to choose later version of Excel? Also, where do you choose c"copy with header"? I couldn't find that option. Thanks

Comment: Nevermind on the Copy with Header. It was a SSMS2008 feature :) However, for the export to Excel, I just tried exporting to Excel 2007 via the wizard and I still get the same error.

Comment: @James - You can still copy the results with the column names. For this, go to "Tools/Query Results/SQL Server/Results To Grid" and check the "Include column headers when copying or saving the results"